# How to retrieve history of pubnub chat in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, pubnub

I am trying for chat application in xamarin.forms using pubnub,i successfully did sending and retrieving messages,but the problem is when i closes the app and reopen is iam not getting previous messages.

```c#
 {
        PNConfiguration config = new PNConfiguration();
        // never share your keys in public, especially pub-key
        config.PublishKey = "pub-c-6de-redacted";
        config.SubscribeKey = "sub-c-85f-redacted";
        config.Uuid = username;

        config.LogVerbosity = PNLogVerbosity.BODY;
        config.PubnubLog = new Logger();
        _pubnub = new Pubnub(config);

        _pubnub.AddListener(this);

        _pubnub.Subscribe<string>()
            .Channels(new string[] { "my_channel1" })
            .WithPresence()
            .Execute();
        _pubnub.HereNow()
            .Channels(new string[]
            {
                "my_channel1"
            })
            .IncludeUUIDs(true)
            .Async(new HereNowResult());

        _pubnub.History()
            .Channel("my_channel1")
            .IncludeTimetoken(true)
            .Count(100)
            .Async(new DemoHistoryResult());
```

and my publish method is:

```c#
public void PublishMessage(string text,string selectednametoChat)
    {
        _pubnub.Publish()
            .Channel("my_channel1")
            .ShouldStore(true)
            .Message(text)
            .UsePOST(true)
            .Async(new PubnubResult());

    }`
```

Here is method to store previous messages
[I think you mean **retrieve previous messages**]

```c#
 public class DemoHistoryResult : PNCallback<PNHistoryResult>
{
    public static ChatWindowViewModel ChatWindowViewModel { get; set; }

    public override void OnResponse(PNHistoryResult result, PNStatus status)
    {
        try
        {
            if (result.Messages != null && result.Messages.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var message in result.Messages)
                {
                    ChatWindowViewModel.MessagesList.Add(message.Entry.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

how to get the history to the `MessagesList`.

Comment: I'm not sure what your real question is. Are you saying that you can't update your MessagesList with the messages returned by the history call or are there no messages being returned by history call?

Comment: @CraigConover,sorry for not being specific,actually `there no messages being returned by history call` that is the problem i am facing.

Comment: No worries - what are the parameter values you are passing into the history call?

Comment: i already placed the code which i am using for getting history,at publishing i enabled messages to store,at `DemoHistoryResult` iam calling `PNHistoryResult result, PNStatus status` there at result iam getting null.

Comment: Did i miss anything?

Comment: Sorry, not sure how I missed that. All looks fine. Are you certain no messages are returned? I checked your channel and it does have messages in storage. How are you verifying that no messages are returned. Are you debugging and seeing that the `PNHistoryResult result` param has no data or just that your UI is not showing them? Because the issue could be your UI data binding, which I don't have any insights (not a C# guy) but do let me know how you are verifying no messages are returned. Also, I redacted your keys from your code above and added color syntax formatting :)

Comment: Thanks for the modifications :)@Craig Conover,yes i find null at `PNHistoryResult result` while debugging and also empty list at output.

Comment: OK, thanks for verifying. You have PubNub client logging already enabled. Can you provide the full logs when you run your code?

Comment: Sorry,Does the logs means the information providing at output window while running the applcation,

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you can send to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) as a file attachment, it would make troubleshooting this more possible.